# How to create a register file using register, decoder, and 8 to 1 mux in verilog

Tags: verilog, hardware

I'm trying to build a RegisterFile that utilizes these 3 components. I just don't know how to put them all together. I have the start of the register file module but just have no clue how to top end it. Is there any way anyone could explain, I'm just so lost. I also think there may be an issue with my Register module. I really am a novice with verilog, so I'm very confused on most things.

```
module Decoder3To8(input enable, input[2:0] in, output[7:0] out);
    assign d[0]=(~a[2])&(~a[1])&(~a[0]);
    assign d[1]=(~a[2])&(~a[1])&(a[0]);
    assign d[2]=(~a[2])&(a[1])&(~a[0]);
    assign d[3]=(~a[2])&(a[1])&(a[0]);
    assign d[4]=(a[2])&(~a[1])&(~a[0]);
    assign d[5]=(a[2])&(~a[1])&(a[0]);
    assign d[6]=(a[2])&(a[1])&(~a[0]);
    assign d[7]=(a[2])&(a[1])&(a[0]);
endmodule

module Register4Bit(input clock, input clear, input load, input[3:0] in, output reg[3:0] out);
    always@(negedge clock or posedge clear)
    begin
        if(clear)
            out<=4′b0000;
        else
            out[3]<=out[2];
            out[2]<=out[1];
            out[1]<=out[0];
            out[0]<=in[0];
    end
endmodule

module Mux4Bit8To1(input[3:0] in0, input[3:0] in1, input[3:0] in2, input[3:0] in3, input[3:0] in4, input[3:0] in5, input[3:0] in6, input[3:0] in7, input[2:0] selector, output reg[3:0] out);
    assign S0 = selector[0];
    assign S1 = selector[1];
    assign S2 = selector[2];
    assign out = S2 ? (S[1] ? (S[0] ? in7 : in6) : (S[0] ? in5 : in4)) : (S[1] ? (S[0] ? in3 : in2) : (S[0] ? in1 : in0))
endmodule

module RegisterFile(input clock, input clear, input[3:0] write_data, input[2:0] write_index, input write, input[2:0] read_index, output[3:0] read_data);
    reg[7:0] content[3:0];   //this line is initializing the register
    integer i;

    always @(posedge clear, negedge clock).  //this is the senstivity list of the always block
        if (clear) begin
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1)
                    content[i] = 0;   //this line is clearing out all the memory locations
        end else if (write)
            content[write_index] = write_data.  //this line is performing a write operation
        else


endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Verilog describes hardware. As a result the final product is set of **connected** elements. In your case you need to instantiate and connect your modules.

In verilog it looks like the following:

```
module in(input clk, input data, output reg value);
   always @(posedge clk)
      value <= data;
endmodule
```

The above module has clock, input data and output value;

```
module out(input clk, input value, output reg data);
  always @(posedge clk)
     data <= ~value;
endmodule
```

And finally you need to assemble them:

```
module device(input clk, input datain, output dataout);
   wire val;

   in in(clk, datain, val);
   out out(clk, val, dataout);
endmodule
```

in the `device`, two modules are instantiated. The `val` plays a role of a connecting wire which connects output of module `in` with input of module `out`.
So, you can extend this scheme to your model.